# Dell Precision T5600 SAS issue

Tags: raid, hardware, dell, sas, drivers

I'm currently having some issues with my Dell Precision T5600 Workstation (more specifically the Intel C600 SAS Controller).

My problem is that my 2x2TB SAS harddisks are completely unreadable for my computer. They are connected to HDD0 and HDD1 on my motherboard. I've got a 250GB SSD connected to SATA0, where Windows Server 2012 R2 is installed.
I've installed both the SATA and SAS controller (Intel C600) drivers, but the SAS drives doesn't show up in Windows or BIOS. I also believe the SAS controller is onboard (picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfvQr.jpg). I can confirm that my SAS disks works, as they've been tested on another computer recently. However, if I connect a normal SATA disk to any of the HDD0-3 with the same SAS cable, Windows and BIOS finds it immediately.

Somewhere on the interwebs I read it could be because I need something called Intel RAID C600 Upgrade Key, but I've never heard of this. I've tried updating the BIOS from version A9 to A15, which according to Dell support is the newest version. If possible, I'd like to avoid setting up a RAID for the two hard drives.

I've been googling for over 4 hours now and I'm really getting tired of searching. I'm considering throwing away my SAS drives and just replace them with SATA drives.

TL;DR - My T5600 (Windows and BIOS) is unable to read my SAS drives even when the drivers are installed. Normal SATA drives works perfectly with the same cables/connectors.

An additional picture of my device manager in Windows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQBTj.jpg

I appreciate any input on this matter! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Dell System Optimizer and install any new updates listed, including any BIOS updates. Its free and pretty fast, direct from Dell.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Unfortunately it didn't fix the problem. I'm concerned it's related to hardware, and I will likely throw away the SAS drives if I can't find a solution to this problem.

Comment: Is the system under warranty? You should be able to get a diagnosis from Dell. They are usually pretty good at problem detection. But watch out for the hard sell on the fix.

Comment: I wish it was, but the warranty just went out a couple of months ago. :(

Comment: Its still worth a call, under those circumstances you can still get a diagnosis from them "usually". Especially if you are a large/frequent customer